# What is the opposite of $A$ implies $B$?

Tags: first-order-logic

What is the opposite of $A$ implies $B$ i.e. $¬(A \implies B)$?

Comment: What kind of answer do you want? For instance, one could point out that you have given an answer in your own post, namely $¬(A \implies B)$. Clearly that is not your intention, but I'm not sure what your intention actually ***is***.

Comment: If you intend to simplify, then use $(A\implies B)\equiv (\lnot A\lor B) $ to get ($A\land \lnot B)$

Comment: @LeeMosher Heehee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [truth table for logical implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication), we see that $A\implies B$ is not satisfied if and only if both $A$ and $\neg B$ are true.

Conclusion:

$$ \neg\left(A\implies B\right) \equiv A \land \neg B $$

Comment: I thank you for your answer. However, by min terms, the right answer is $(A \wedge B) \vee (¬ A \wedge B) \vee (¬ A \wedge ¬ B)$, isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand why you would accept my answer and then immediately ask for further clarification... You shouldn't accept an answer until you are satisfied with it...

Comment: I want to understand it by means of my own knowledge.

Comment: What you wrote in your previous comment is equivalent to " $A$ implies $B$", isn't it?

Comment: It is yes correct

Comment: So have I answered your questions? I'm not sure

Comment: Sure. I thank you, fellow.